# e.target.value shows values one key 'behind'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Input type with id 'typehere'. There is a `keydown` event set on `typhere`. The simple problem is that `e.srcElement.value` seems to have a value one key behind. i.e. if the value should 's' , its consoled'logged as blank '' . If I type 'ss' , the value shown is 's' . I can't seem to figure this one out.

`console.log(e)`, shows the correct value of `e.srcElement.value` (in the console), but `console.log(e.srcElement.value)` shows the wrong value. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
            selectOption = document.getElementById('choose_colony') ;

            document.body.onload = function () {
                typehere = document.getElementById('typehere') ;

                addAnEvent(typehere,"keydown",handleKeyDownevent,false )  ;
            }

            function handleKeyDownevent (e) {
                e = e || window.event ;
                if (xmlHttp) {
                    try {
                        //xmlHttp.open('GET' , 'async.txt', true ) ;
                           console.log(e.srcElement.value ) ;
                       var target=  e.target || e.srcElement ;
                        var typed = target.value      ;
                        if (typed != ""){
                            console.log('sennding request') ;
                            //ajax request
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(e.srcElement.value + "is blank") ;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        console.log('could not connect to server') ;
                    }
                }

            }
</script>
```

The script tag are before the `</body>` tag btw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(For typeable characters, you typically want `keypress` rather than `keydown` as `keypress` repeats.)

`keydown` is fired before the value has changed (as does `keypress`), not least so you can cancel the keypress, so if you want to process the value after it's changed, you may want to defer your call using `setTimeout(func, 0)`. Your call will get processed after the event chain unwinds. (Typically within 5-10 milliseconds.)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/irirox)

So in your code, that might look like this:

```
addAnEvent(typehere,"keydown",function(e) { // or "keypress"
    e = e || window.event;
    setTimeout(function() {
        handleKeyDownevent(e);
    }, 0);
},false )  ;
```

Comment: I am having a lil trouble implementing the same in my code. But this is clearly the solution. Thanks

Comment: Couldn´t `keyup` be useful? ...and for how long should one wait for the user to release the key?

Comment: @Stefan: It becomes a non-issue if you use `keypress`.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup event instead of keydown.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer lies in the fact that when you are trying to determine the value of a variable that is within an event, it is processed by an event handler, and therefore it is best to simply log the event itself.  So you could try modifying your code to accommodate for that, to see if helps.  Also, I disagree with above answer about needing to set/include a time-out (function), unless you are trying to cancel any keystrokes, etc. To clarify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
        selectOption = document.getElementById('choose_colony') ;

        document.body.onload = function () {
            typehere = document.getElementById('typehere');
            addAnEvent(typehere, "keydown", function(e) { 
                e = e || window.event;
                handleKeyDownevent(e);}, false);
        }
function handleKeyDownevent (e) {
            e = e || window.event ;
            if (xmlHttp) {
                try {
                    //xmlHttp.open('GET' , 'async.txt', true ) ;
                       console.log(e.srcElement.value ) ;
                   var target=  e.target || e.srcElement ;
                    var typed = target.value      ;
                    if (typed != ""){
                        console.log('sennding request') ;
                        //ajax request
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(e.srcElement.value + "is blank") ;
                    }
                }
                catch(e) {
                    console.log('could not connect to server') ;
                }
            }
          return true;
        }
</script>
```

I hope that helps you out.  The `return true` at the bottom allows the browser's default response.